# How to optimize a Binding list?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need some your lights to help me solve an issue.
The codes below works but I want to optimize this because I am newbie in cs coding and I know its not the good way even if it works..

I have a PageModel with some strings

**PageModel.cs**

```
namespace myapp
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        public string IngredientName { get; set; }
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Detail { get; set; }    
     }
}
```

Then the View page with Bindings

**Page.xaml**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myapp »
             x:Class=« app.Views.Page>
    <ContentPage.Content>        
      <StackLayout>
           <ListView 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding IngredientList}"
                  HasUnevenRows="true"
                  SeparatorVisibility="None"
                   ItemTapped="OnItemSelected">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                     <ViewCell> 
                                        <Grid>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding IngredientName}"  />
                                           <Label Text="{Binding Detail}"  />
                                           <Label Text="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                                       </Grid>                                      
                                    </ViewCell>
                             </DataTemplate>
                     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

The list is displaying according to the string passing in the constructor (PizzaName)
So you have a list of different ingredients (in case of)

**Page.cs**

```
namespace myapp.Views
{
    public partial class Page : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Ingredient> IngredientList { get; set; }

        public Page(string PizzaName)
            {
            InitializeComponent();

            switch ( PizzaName )
            {
                case « Pepperoni »:
                    IngredientList = new List<Ingredient>
                {
                new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Tomato », Quantity = "10 gr", Detail = "Tomato detail" },
                new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Mushrooms »,  Quantity = "20 gr", Detail = "Mushrooms detail" },
                new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Pepper »,  Quantity = " 5 gr ", Detail = " Pepper detail" }
                };
                    break;

                case « Regina »:
                    IngredientList = new List<Ingredient>
                {

               new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Butter », Quantity = "10 gr ", Detail = "Butter detail" },
               new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Mushrooms »,  Quantity = "10 gr", Detail = "Mushrooms detail" },
               new Ingredient { IngredientName = « Flour »,  Quantity = "5 gr", Detail = "Flour detail" }             
         };
                    break;
            }
                    BindingContext = this;
        }

    private async void OnItemSelected(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mydetails = e.Item as Ingredient;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(mydetails.IngredientName, mydetails.Quantity, mydetails.Detail));

        }
    }
}
```

**So I want to create a list in a separate file (maybe ViewModel Page) which will contains a global list of all the ingredients without Quantity string and add an ID string.**

Something like this
**ViewModel.cs**

```
GlobalIngredientList = new List<Ingredient>
                {
                new Ingredient { ID = " 1 ", IngredientName = "Tomato", Detail = "Tomato detail" },
                new Ingredient { ID = "2", IngredientName = "Mushrooms",  Detail = "Mushrooms detail" },
                new Ingredient { ID = "3", IngredientName = " Pepper ", Detail = "Pepper detail " },
               new Ingredient { ID = " 4 ", IngredientName = " Butter ",  Detail = " Butter detail " },
               new Ingredient {ID = " 5 ",  IngredientName = " Mushrooms ", Detail = "Mushrooms detail" },
               new Ingredient { ID = " 6 ", IngredientName = " Flour ",  Detail = " Flour detail " }    


                };
```

Then in my Page.cs I want to call a new List but only set the ID of GlobalList and the Quantity

**Page.cs**

```
namespace myapp.Views
{
    public partial class Page : ContentPage
    {
        public List<Ingredient> IngredientList { get; set; }

        public Page(string PizzaName)
            {
            InitializeComponent();

            switch ( PizzaName )
            {
                case « Pepperoni »:
        IngredientList = new List<Ingredient>
                {
                new Ingredient { ID = " 1 ",  Quantity = "10 gr " },
                new Ingredient { ID = " 3",   Quantity = "20 gr" },
                new Ingredient { ID = " 5 ", ,  Quantity = "5 gr " }
                };

        break;

                case « Regina »:
                    IngredientList = new List<Ingredient>
                {
                 new Ingredient { ID = " 6 ",  Quantity = "10 gr " },
                new Ingredient { ID = " 3 ",   Quantity = " 20 gr " },
                new Ingredient { ID =" 2 ", ,  Quantity = " 5 gr " }

         };
                    break;
            }
                    BindingContext = this;
        }

    private async void OnItemSelected(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
        {
            var mydetails = e.Item as Ingredient;
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailPage(mydetails.IngredientName, mydetails.Quantity, mydetails.Detail));

        }

    }
}
```

Finally I want to avoid to repeat the ingredients name and details in cs file and still get in my xaml page IngredientName, Quantity and Detail..
and because my global list could contain more than 100 ingredients :/

Thanks for your lights

Comment: you either need to put this data in a local sqlite db, or in a remote db you access via a webservice.  Hardcoding all of that data is a bad idea

Comment: How to set datas in sqlite db ?